# Read csv files from multiple folders using a for loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, path

My code will read from a csv file and perform multiple operations/calculations then create another csv file, i have 8 folders to read/write from and i want my code to iterate through them one by one

lets say i have folders named Folder1 to Folder8, first of all how do i specify my code to read from a different directory instead of the default one where the python script exists?

this is part of my code

```
#read the columns from CSV
MAXCOLS = Number_Of_Buses + 1
Bus_Vol = [[] for _ in range(MAXCOLS)]
with open('p_voltage_table_output.csv', 'rb') as input:
    for row in csv.reader(input, delimiter=','):
        for i in range(MAXCOLS):
            Bus_Vol[i].append(row[i] if i < len(row) else '')

for i in xrange(1,MAXCOLS):
    dummy=0
    #print('Bus_Vol[{}]: {}'.format(i, Bus_Vol[i]))
```

i want to be able to specify the directory folder to folder1 and also iterate through folder1 to folder8 which all have the same csv file with the same name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read a directory other than where your script is located, you need to provide python the absolute path to the directory.

Windows style: c:\path\to\directory

*nix style: /path/to/directory

In either case it'll be a string.

You didn't specify if your target folders were in the same directory or not. If they are, it's a bit easier.

```
import os
path_to_parent = "/path/to/parent"

for folder in os.listdir(path_to_parent):
    for csv_file in os.listdir(os.path.join(path_to_parent, folder)):
        # Do whatever to your csv file here
```

If your folders are spread out on your system, then you have to provide an absolute path to each one:

```
import os
paths_to_folders = ['/path/to/folder/one', '/path/to/folder/two']

for folder in paths_to_folders:
   for csv_file in os.listdir(folder):
        # Do whatever to your csv file
```

Comment: Awesome! Good luck on the rest of the project